# JQuery draggable snap cancel with key

Tags: jquery, triggers, keyboard-shortcuts, jquery-ui-draggable

While at IE this works in chrome it wont: "Snap" Option in draggable stop working while pressing "Ctrl", i cant even seem to get the alert("SNAP") when pressing ctrl while dragging. my tries are:

```
 $("#object").draggable({
        handle: '#handle_',
        containment: '#MainBody',
        snap: ".drag_alignLines", // Setting snap to alignment lines
        snapTolerance: 15
                            }).bind('keydown', function(event){ 
                        alert("SNAP");
                    if(event.ctrlKey)
                    {
                        alert("hi");
                        this.draggable( "option", "snap", false );
                    }
                });
```

cant get Chrome to catch the ctrl key while dragging...
and even in IE the: "this.draggable( "option", "snap", false );" just dont make it stop snap while dragging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is reset the snap option like so:

```
$( "#object" ).draggable( "option", "snap", false );
```

And remember to set it back to the original value on a regular click. Here is the relevant section of [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYPJz/2/):

```
$("#object").draggable({
containment: '#MainBody',
snapTolerance: 15,
start: function(event)
    {
        if(event.ctrlKey)
        {
            $(this).draggable("option", "snap", false);
        }else {
            $(this).draggable("option", "snap", '.drag_alignLines');
        }

    }});
```

It binds to 'start' rather than on 'keydown' so you don't have to aim before hitting Control.

Comment: If you want to switch between snap on and off dynamically whilst dragging, you can also add the handler to the drag event as well. This means if you hold ctrl whilst dragging, it doesn't snap and as soon as you release the key it starts snapping again, even without releasing the mouse button.